Azure DB to timezone does not convert
I am trying to convert the timezone of GETDATE() by using AT TIME ZONE. But for some reason no matter what I do, it always stays in UTC. I tried using SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() instead, I've also have tried double conversion, but it always stays at UTC.

This is the query I used:
SELECT 
    SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() as base,
    SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'Central European Standard Time' as option_1,
    (SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') AT TIME ZONE 'Central European Standard Time' as option_2,
    SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() AT TIME ZONE 'Central European Standard Time' as option_3
;

Normally the time should be +1 hour but it all just stays at +0h

I can't replicate your problem using your code, or GETDATE(): db<>fiddle Perhaps the problem is not SQL, but what ever application you are using to display the data.

By using your code, I am not getting your output

I do agree with @Thom A's comment that the problem is not with your query that even I have tried the same query in Azure SQL database, and it gave me the expected output.
Based on the output image that you have provided, I can say that you are previewing data from an Azure Data factory or synapse pipeline by giving the above query in copy activity or lookup activity query option.
In the activity data preview of ADF pipeline, I got the same results as yours upon trying your query.

In ADF, AFAIK, the activity output or previews from query option of the activity only follows the UTC even though you have provided the correct query. I came to this conclusion after trying the same query in the lookup activity and it gave the same result in the activity output as well.
But apart from the activity outputs and data previews it will convert the values to required time zones. I have added the above SQL query in a copy activity source and used a sample delimited as target. Upon executing the copy activity, you can see the values converted to expected time zone in the target csv file. It's the same result for the SQL table target as well.

So, it won't affect the data when you copy the above data to any target. But if you want use activity outputs in the pipeline, you need to convert the values to required time zones explicitly using ADF dynamic expressions.

you are right its in a copy data in ADF. my apologies for not clarifying this. so it's only on preview where it acts like this.
